# Repeat code, change variable?

Tags: loop

Is this possible in WordPress?

Like if I use a piece of code to display Post1 image+title and some more code to display six more posts in that category...

But then to do the next category I have to paste the whole code in again and change the category.

Can I just code "repeat, but change variable to ___ and variable to ____?

Thanks,
JH

```
---
<div class="category-container">
        <div class="category-container-category-title" style="background-color:#004377;">
            Cat 1
        </div>  
        <div class="category-container-category-post" >
            <?php $posts = get_posts( "cat='50'&numberposts=1" ); ?>
            <?php if( $posts ) : ?>
            <?php foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" >
                <div class="thumbnail-box" style="background-color:#004377;">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : the_post_thumbnail('thumb-thumb'); endif; ?>
                    <h3><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h3>
                </div>
            </a>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="category-container-category-posts">
        <?php
        $args=array(
        'cat' => '50',
        'offset' => 1, 
        'showposts'=>6,
        'caller_get_posts'=>1
        );
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        $offset = 3;
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
            <div>
                <h5 style="padding-bottom:25px;"><b>
                    <?php the_title(); ?></b>
                </h5>
            </div>
        </a>
        <?php
        endwhile;
        } //if ($my_query)
        wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
        ?>
    </div>
---
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Like this. I'd like to repeat the whole code, but replace cat1 with cat50 for example, and, though not necessary -- it would just mean more/less coding, replace the title "Cat 1" with something else.

Comment: Yes, of course you can. Build a function, or a loop, but this is pure (basic) PHP and is not specific to WordPress so far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

So you basically don't want to keep repeating the same HTML over and over. You should put all of the tags and categories you want to display into an array. Then iterate over that array, querying and printing HTML each time. You could use conditionals to display different HTML where necessary.

```
$terms = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'terms' => array(1)
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'tag',
        'terms' => array('code')
    )
    //...
);
```

Then iterate over these...

```
foreach( $terms as $set ) {

    //build args
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );

    if( $set['taxonomy'] == 'tag' )
        $args['tag_slug__and'] = $set['terms'];

    if( $set['taxonomy'] == 'category' )
        $args['category__in'] = $set['terms'];

    //create new WP_Query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $query->have_posts() ) : 
        while( $query->have_posts() ) :
            $query->the_post();
            ?>

                <!-- HTML -->

            <?php
        endwhile;
    endif;

}
```

You could also bypass building your own `$terms` array altogether by using [`get_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms), but if you are trying to show variations in display, the above should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. This looks good. I have no idea how to implement this, though. Still, appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use the power of a php function.

```
function repeat_me($var1, $var2) {
    echo '<div>my markup..'.$var1.'</div>'.$var2;
}
repeat_me($id1, $obj1);
repeat_me($id2, $obj2);
...
```

Comment: Hi Fleuv,

OK, I've bee trying this all morning. I get the concept of this (just learned how to code php functions), but not how to apply it to shortcutting code on page. I want to have on page "function + cat=33 + "funtion2" and have the two sides of my php in those two functions, right?